# The top value of a position relative div is weird in chrome in dynamic page

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

The **dynamic** page only has one div like this;

```
<div id='test' style="position:relative;top:-130px;width:10px;height:10px"></div>

alert($('#test').css('top')) // why the result is not -130 in chrome?
```

Here is the testcase.
http://jsfiddle.net/B6ea6/1/

---

Thank you for your quick feedbacks.
Because I zoomed in the chrome by **ctrl + middle mouse button**,but that is ok in IE and FireFox.

Comment: It is "-130px" in my chrome. Check yours properly.

Comment: In my Chrome is -130px output

Comment: "-130px" on Chrome 24.0.1312.52 too!